# Python- Mask Detection Nerual Network using Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

So this is my first real try on neural networks with keras. I've been trying to make a classifier which decides wether someone is wearing a mask. Below i provided my model. I achived a training accuracy of about 87 percent and a validation accuracy of 85 percent. With own images it performs mostly well too. I created my own dataset with about 600 images for each of the two classes. However I have some questions.

- Is it correct? Any suggested improvements? As I said this is my first neural network project i dont really know if i made anything wrong(which I most likely did)
- How would i implemet this to predict on camera feed and not only images. Would I just get the frames from for example opencv and predict those? Any review and/or help is highly appreciated

This is my model:

```
from keras.layers import Dense, Input, Dropout, GlobalAveragePooling2D, Flatten, Conv2D, BatchNormalization, Activation, MaxPooling2D
from keras.models import Model, Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

NAME = "mask-detection"
tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir="logs/{}".format(NAME))
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1 / 255)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'data/train',
    target_size=(100, 100),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='categorical',
    color_mode = "grayscale"
)

label_map = (train_generator.class_indices)

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'data/test',
    target_size=(100, 100),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='categorical',
    color_mode = "grayscale"
)

model=Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(100,(3,3),padding='same', input_shape=(100,100,1)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(100,(3,3), padding='same',))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(50,activation='relu'))

model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(
    optimizer=RMSprop(lr=0.0001),
    loss="binary_crossentropy",
    metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit(train_generator, epochs=20, callbacks=[tensorboard])
model.evaluate(validation_generator)
model.save('saved_model/model')
model.summary()
print(label_map)
```

And with this i predict the imgs:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image

model =  tf.keras.models.load_model('saved_model/model')
predictions = ["Mask", "No Mask"]

def predict_mask(img):
    x = image.load_img(img, color_mode="grayscale", target_size=(100, 100))
    x = image.img_to_array(x)
    x = np.expand_dims(x, axis= 0)
    x = np.array(x).astype("float32")/255  
    x = x.reshape([1, 100, 100, 1])

    classes = model.predict(x)
    return predictions[np.argmax(classes)]

img = "test.png"

print(predict_mask(img))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things you can do. If you want to use your existing model then I recommend you use the keras callbacks ReduceLROnPlateau and ModelCheckpoint. The first enables you to use an adjustable learning rate. Set it up to monitor validation loss. A typical use is shown in the code below where if the validation loss fails to reduce on an epoch the learning rate is reduced by 50% .This allows you to use a larger learning rate initially and have it reduce automatically in later epochs. The second enables you to save the model with the lowest validation loss. Typical application is shown in the code below. Documentation for these callbacks is [here.](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/) After training load this model to do predictions. If you want to get better results I recommend you try transfer learning. Many models are available with documentation [here.](https://keras.io/api/applications/) I prefer to use the MobileNet model because it has only 4 million trainable parameters versus say 140 million for VGG16 and is about as accurate in most cases. Code below shows typical use.

```
rlrp=tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(
    monitor='val_loss', factor=0.5, patience=1, verbose=0, mode='auto',
    min_delta=0.0001, cooldown=0, min_lr=0)
checkpoint_filepath = '/tmp/checkpoint'
mcp=tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_filepath,
     monitor='val_loss', verbose=0, save_best_only=True,
    save_weights_only=False, mode='auto', save_freq='epoch', options=None)
callbacks=[rlrp,mcp]
mobile = tf.keras.applications.mobilenet.MobileNet( include_top=False,
                                                           input_shape=(image_size,image_size,3),
                                                           pooling='max', weights='imagenet',
                                                           alpha=1, depth_multiplier=1,dropout=.5)
x=mobile.layers[-1].output  
x=keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis=-1, momentum=0.99, epsilon=0.001 )(x)
predictions=Dense (2, activation='softmax')(x)
model = Model(inputs=mobile.input, outputs=predictions)    
for layer in model.layers:
    layer.trainable=True
model.compile(Adamax(lr=.05), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy']) 
data=model.fit(x=train_generator,  epochs=20, verbose=1, 
                   callbacks=callbacks,  validation_data=validation_generator, shuffle=True)
```

Comment: Ok thanks I'll try that out